# Requests http lib: include X-Request-ID

Tags: python, python-requests

I use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) HTTP client library in Python.

Sometimes an HTTP request fails, and I get an HTTP response with status `500`.

This can be in CI or production, and I see something like this:

```
AssertionError: 200 != 500 : <Response [500]>
```

That does not help much.

It would be very great if I could see the `X-Request-ID` in the above message. In my environment, this exists for every HTTP response.

This means the HTTP response object of the requests library should add it.

I want the `repr()` to look like `<Response [500] XejfkmxcPfhM3dqhY2HJgQAAAAM>`

Since this is not my code, but the code of the requests lib, I am unsure how I could implement this.

How to include the `X-Request-ID` in the repr() of requests response objects?

Comment: Two options: 1. Fork and create your own copy 2. Monkeypatch `requests.Response` with your own copy of `Response` overriding `__repr__`

Comment: Did you try to use something like SENTRY & RAVEN (production) - and see what it catches ? or recreate the error in TEST ENV  with break-point ?

Comment: @OhadtheLad AFAIK sentry is a commercial service. If possible I prefer open source solutions. I have not tried sentry up to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to create my own "response flow" in case I can do it, instead of using any sort of [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). I've checked sources of the requests library and we are good to go there! We can implement the required feature using [requests Event Hooks system](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks).

There is a working example where we can do anything with the response. The only change is that we have to use our own `Session` object instance for using the feature. But! If we don't want to override any source code, we can do a one linemonkey-patch, override the default `Session` class for the default api calls and it will work everywhere like a charm.

My solution is here

```
import requests


class ResponseVerbose(requests.Response):
    extra_header_repr = 'X-Request-Guid'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Response [{}] {}: {}>'.format(
            self.status_code,
            self.extra_header_repr,
            self.headers.get(self.extra_header_repr, 'None')
        )


class Session(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hooks['response'] = self.build_response

    @staticmethod
    def build_response(resp, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Let's rebuild the source response into required verbose response object using all fields from the original

        FYI: requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.build_response
        """
        response = ResponseVerbose()
        response.status_code = resp.status_code
        response.headers = resp.headers
        response.encoding = resp.encoding
        response.raw = resp.raw
        response.reason = response.raw.reason
        response.url = resp.url
        response.cookies = resp.cookies.copy()
        response.request = resp.request
        response.connection = resp.connection

        return response


def main():
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

    sess = Session()
    print('response using our own session object: {}'.format(sess.get(url)))

    import requests.api
    requests.api.sessions.Session = Session
    print('response using monkey patched global Session class: {}'.format(requests.get(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

outputs

```
# python test123.py
response using our own session object: <Response [200] X-Request-Guid: 0c446bb5-7c96-495d-a831-061f5e3c2afe>
response using monkey patched global Session class: <Response [200] X-Request-Guid: 1db5aea7-8bc9-496a-addc-1231e8543a89>
```

### One more shorter example which uses `Response.__getstate__()` function

More info https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L654

> As I see from the source code, you shouldn't do it for very large content responses since it fetches the whole `resp.content` to be able to convert the response state into a state dict. So use it only if you know that there are not gigabytes in responses :)

The function looks much easier.

```
import requests


class ResponseVerbose(requests.Response):
    extra_header_repr = 'X-Request-Guid'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Response [{}] {}: {}>'.format(
            self.status_code,
            self.extra_header_repr,
            self.headers.get(self.extra_header_repr, 'None')
        )


class Session(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hooks['response'] = self.build_response

    @staticmethod
    def build_response(resp, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Let's rebuild the source response into required verbose response object using all fields from the original

        FYI: requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.build_response
        """

        response = ResponseVerbose()
        for k, v in resp.__getstate__().items():
            setattr(response, k, v)

        return response


def main():
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

    sess = Session()
    print('response using our own session object: {}'.format(sess.get(url)))

    import requests.api
    requests.api.sessions.Session = Session
    print('response using monkey patched global Session class: {}'.format(requests.get(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> The solution prints StackOverflow's extra response header `X-Request-Guid` just for example. This extra header I did easily configurable just to show how it could be done in the right way.

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately `build_response()` is still long (for example copy cookie). Maybe the author of the request lib would allow a pull request to make changing the Response class more simple?

Comment: Why not, it could be a good feature to pass Response & Request classes. But not right now I believe :) As a quick solution it looks great to me :)

Comment: @guettli added an easier solution using magic method for dumping the response state to a state dict. Looks much cleaner :)

Comment: Still I think that changing the Response-Class should be easier. Maybe the author of the request lib would allow a pull request to make changing the Response class more simple?

Comment: Why not, you can try to talk with the author :)

Comment: somebody already asked: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3360 Maybe this pattern would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571848/name-of-design-pattern-get-class-from-class-level

Comment: I am very sorry, I forgo to give the bounty. Should I start a new one?

Comment: I don't know :) if you want you can do it)

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to overwrite the *requests.models.Response.__repr__* method at runtime (also called [[Wikipedia]: Monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch))
 as @heemayl commented. Note that this is one variant (the simplest, I think) of this way.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import requests


def __response_repr(self):
    repr_headers = (
        "X-Request-ID",
        "Content-Encoding",  # @TODO - cfati: For demo purposes only!!! DELETE (COMMENT) THIS LINE.
    )
    repr_parts = ["<Response [{0:d}]".format(self.status_code)]
    for repr_header in repr_headers:
        if repr_header in self.headers:
            repr_parts.append(" {0:}".format(self.headers[repr_header]))
    repr_parts.append(">")
    return "".join(repr_parts)


def main(*argv):
    if argv:
        print("Monkey patch {0:}...\n".format(requests.models.Response))
        requests.models.Response.__str__ = requests.models.Response.__repr__  # Keep the original __str__ behavior
        requests.models.Response.__repr__ = __response_repr

    url = "https://www.google.com"
    print("Connecting to: {0:s} ...\n".format(url))

    r = requests.get(url)
    print("str(Response): {0:s}".format(str(r)))
    print("repr(Response): {0:s}".format(repr(r)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059193447]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Connecting to: https://www.google.com ...
>
> str(Response): <Response [200]>
> repr(Response): <Response [200]>
>
> Done.
>
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059193447]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py dummy_arg_to_trigger_monkey_patch
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Monkey patch <class 'requests.models.Response'>...
>
> Connecting to: https://www.google.com ...
>
> str(Response): <Response [200]>
> repr(Response): <Response [200] gzip>
>
> Done.
> ```